# is unique email address from Apple when performing 'Sign in using Apple' always change?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make login using OAuth2 using Apple Sign in. and I need to save the user email to the server.

after reading [Sign in with Apple and authenticate with Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple#sign_in_with_apple_and_authenticate_with_firebase) , it said that

> Unlike other providers supported by Firebase Auth, Apple does not
> provide a photo URL.
>
> Also, when the user chooses not to share their email with the app,
> Apple provisions a unique email address for that user (of the form
> xyz@privaterelay.appleid.com), which it shares with your app. If you
> configured the private email relay service, Apple forwards emails sent
> to the anonymized address to the user's real email address.

apple will generate unique fake email like `xyz@privaterelay.appleid.com` if the user refuses to share their original email.

if the user logout and then login again, will the fake email will be the same? or apple will generate a new fake email like `new123@privaterelay.appleid.com` ?

Comment: You only get the email and name the first time the user signs in.  The next time you just get the user identifier.  If the user deletes the account associated with your service from their iCloud settings and then logs in to your service then you will see them as a new user with a new email and new unique identifier

Comment: @Paulw11 so for Apple sign in, we need to save the user identifier in the server instead of saving the email? am I right?

Comment: Yes. You should save the unique identifier as the account identifier. You should also save the email if you want to be able to send emails to the user since you won't be able to get them email address again

Answer (score 0):

As discussed here [Answered by official](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121496), You only get the actual email address once when the Apple oAuth flows for the first time. Based on the thread, You should be taking the email from there and you should not update the email in your database from subsequent authentication.